# Android Media player not working on button click

Tags: android

As the title suggests, I'm looking to play a small sound clip when a button is click - very basic. However, when I click the button the first time I get the following error:

```
08-01 15:01:58.547  18991-18991/? E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
08-01 15:02:01.030  18991-19008/za.co.site.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -1010)
08-01 15:02:01.054  18991-18991/za.co.site.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-1010)
```

When I click the button again I get, the following error:

```
08-01 15:07:09.586  18991-18991/za.co.site.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
08-01 15:07:09.586  18991-18991/za.co.site.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
08-01 15:07:09.587  18991-18991/za.co.site.app E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
```

I'm using a fragement. Here is the code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    final Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setEnabled(false);

    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.clip);

    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
            b.setEnabled(true);

            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mp.start();

                }
            });
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

After reading around the first error is to do with Android not finding the file. However, the file is in a raw folder inside the res folder and android is definitely picking up the clip with R.raw.clip. By using the OnPreparedListener, this should stop the second error from occurring because the app caters for the clip to be ready before the button is pressed.

I'm not too sure when I'm doing wrong, thoughts?

Comment: I think it's about the file you want to play ,change it and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Media player try to use mp3 files. The file I was using was a .wav file. The moment I made the file an mp3 file it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prepare if you are creating this way. Just call start().

This is because the file is local.